# class can i use the properties of the name space from base class

Tags: c#, .net

Have a simple question, well looks to be simple but i have been searching for the reason could not get it back.

1. If i have imported a namespace in base class can i use the properties of the name space ( classes, objects, method etc.) in all the derived class?

for example

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class MyBase
{
     public string GetName()
        {
            List<string> ss = new List<string>();
            return ss.ToString();
        }
}
```

Can i use the List property in all child classed from my base with out having the namespaces? like

```
public class myChild : MyBase
    {
        public string GetName()
        {
            List<string> ss = new List<string>();
            return ss.ToString();
        }
    }
```

If not Why? Also the same behavior i have noticed in partial classes .. can some one explain the reason behind this?

Comment: Did you try the code above?  Did it compile?  Did you get a warning or an error from the compiler?  If the code compiled, did the resulting assembly function as expected?  You say, "the same behavior I have noticed in partial classes": what behavior is that?  You've asked some questions about behavior, but you haven't described any behavior that you've observed.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're asking the following

> If a Parent type is defined in a file that imports a namespace, do I have to reimport that namespace if I derive from Parent?

If so the answer is yes.  A child type doesn't inherit the namespaces which are imported in the file in which the parent type is defined (partially because with `partial` types a type can be defined in multiple files with conflicting namespaces).  Every file is compiled based on it's own set of imports.

Answer (score 2):

`using` statements are not executable code, and they do not apply to classes or members of classes.  Rather, they give the compiler information about how to resolve type names.  A `using` statement is only in scope in the file in which contains it; furthermore, if it is inside a namespace declaration, it's only in force within that namespace declaration.

Note that it's possible to have more than one namespace declaration in a file, so:

```
namespace N
{
    using System.IO;
    partial class C
    {
        public FileInfo SomeFileInfo { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace N
{
    partial class C
    {
        public DirectoryInfo SomeDirectoryInfo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The reference to `DirectoryInfo` can't be resolved, because `using System.IO;` is not in scope at that point.

Comment: Random aside, the using statements do appear in the PDB. It's put there to facilitate the debugging experience